# Team Foundation Server 2010 Not Honoring My .tfignore file

Tags: tfs

Here's my .tfignore exactly. It is in the root directory of the branch and committed to TFS, but it is never honored. I imagine I'm missing some syntactic subtlety not clear to me from reading [TechNet's article on the .tfignore file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx#tfignore), but what?

```
### Team Foundation Server Source Control Ruleset Overrides for the Web Project
### These are created to ensure the proper files for the BEC Website end up
### under control.

## INCLUSIONS
# It is truly silly that VS excludes "Debug"...
!debug

# Include any binaries from sources, because they're all third party...
\sources\*.exe

## EXCLUSIONS
# Exclude site-specific tmp, cache and log folders...
wwwroot\administrator\cache
wwwroot\administrator\log
wwwroot\cache
wwwroot\log
wwwroot\tmp
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably not missing any syntactic subtleties, [.tfignore is a new feature in VS2012 and seems to also require TFS2012](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/tfsgeneral/thread/7fe11e31-0d0b-42ed-ae4f-32de86a65c78).

Comment: Ah! Enlightening. I agree with the conclusion you linked. I suppose I'll find out for sure when we upgrade our TFS...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will count as an answer but my .tfignore file only seems to be taken into account when checking in individual projects, if I do a check in from the solution it is completely ignored.  I've tested it on several machines at this point and see the same pattern.  So I have to have my team either manually going through and excluding files when doing a full solution check in or just checking in individual projects.  Both are horrible work arounds but at this point I haven't found a better solution.

Comment: Nick G, I assume you're on TFS 2012 though, right? As discussed above, .tfignore is not supported below that level. Thank you for your notation though; I'll keep that in mind.