# Check in packages folder contents

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

When I check in my projects into VSTS -- aka VSO -- should I check in the packages folder contents?

I checked in a couple of projects into VSTS "without" the packages folder contents. I downloaded the those projects onto another computer and now I'm having a lot of trouble restoring packages.

Is it standard practice to check in projects with "packages" folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically checkin the .config file(s) in the root but nothing else. Then, make sure that vs is setup to restore nuget packages when you build.

On the solution, goto Tools->Options->Package Manager->Allow NuGet to download missing packages. That should work.

And, since I have to edit every answer I type as I get it wrong the first time ... [here is a good outline of what you need to do to exclude those files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28682504/4747123) in case you need it.

In most of our solutions, we checkin the /packages/repository.config file at the solution level and then all of the packages.config files in each project.