# How do I stop TFS constantly trying to add nuget packages folder?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

Is there some sort of .gitignore for TFS? There's nothing in the context menus.

Comment: It seems there a .tfsignore file you can add. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms245454%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#tfignore

Comment: No `s` just `.tfignore`

Comment: Indeed Nikola, thank you. Also of interest, on Windows 10, you can't create a .tfignore file through explorer,. So creating a IHateTFS.txt file and attempting to rename it to .tfignore gives the error "You must type a filename". using a command prompt you can do "echo IHateTFS > .tfignore" to create the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There has been a very detailed answer to solve this from *Pharylon*  in the question [Get TFS to ignore my packages folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143925/get-tfs-to-ignore-my-packages-folder)

Moreover, **it's able to create a `.tfignore` file through file explorer.** You just need to rename a new .txt file with **".tfignore."** (make sure also delete txt) It will auto change to the right `.tfignore` file.

You can also use the auto automatically generated `.tfignore` file, follow detailed steps from [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms245454%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#tfignore).

Comment: I don't believe the rename step works under Windows 10. Here's a screen shot of what happens when I do. Works from the command line though.  http://imgur.com/TRjOD9k

Comment: Test pass with WIndows10. You should unmark the "Hide extensions for known file types "  in `Folder Options-- View` (click  view in File Explorer ,then click options) first. Then it will display XXX.txt.  After this, try it again.

Comment: This isn't the option Patrick. I have "Hide extensions..." disabled (so I can see extensions" as one of the 90 things I do everytime I reinstall the OS. It' interesting it works for you. I'm using Windows 10 Pro and the test fails on three seperate machines. Create an empty "new document.txt" from the context menu, then just attempt to rename it. Fails with the error I included in the screenshot above on all machines :/

Comment: As an aside, I can't actually remember changing it recently, so I wonder if it's included in the settings now synced with your Microsoft account. It's one of the features of Windows 10 I do like. It is "off" though, I need extensions!