# TFS: Why is Cloak grayed out?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfignore

I'm on VS Community 2017.

I'm trying to permanently ignore the packages folder from being checked-in.
I went to Source Control Explorer, but the Cloak option in the file/folder's context menu, under Advanced is grayed out:

[image]

I tried adding a `.tfignore` file in the root folder adding `packages` and `/packages` to it, but it didn't do the job.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Cloaking is the process of defining which folders or files should be
>   ** ignored by the workspace on your development machine.**

Which may not be suitable for your situation. You could only cloak files/folders already in source control. If your packages folder is newly add in pending changes and not checked in, the cloak option should be grayed out.

Give a try with declaring below instead of only ignore `\packages`  in your .tfignore file and add a *disableSourceControlIntegration* in a *NuGet.config* file, try again.

```
\packages
!\packages\repositories.config
```

For more detailed steps please refer to this question: [Get TFS to ignore my packages folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143925/get-tfs-to-ignore-my-packages-folder)

Another way is only check the packages folder to TFS (without any files or sub-folders) and then do the cloaked operation.

More info about the nuget package restore/TFS  please refer this tutorial-- [Package Restore with Team Foundation Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#package-restore-with-team-foundation-build)

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#package-restore-with-team-foundation-build) link was most helpful, please include this in your answer. What did the trick was the .nuget\NuGet.config file.

Answer (score 1):

You can only cloak things that are committed to the server already and since you have a pending add on the packages folder, it is not.

The package folder is added byt the Package Manager, but you can configure it to skip that step by creating a NuGet.config file in the solution directory setting `disableSourceControlIntegration` to `true`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <solution>
        <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
    </solution>
</configuration>
```