# TFS Solution Check in error Could not find a part of the path

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, json.net

This MVC webapp project is building fine, no errors or warnings. It can be published and the site comes up as expected.

The Project can be checked into TFS just fine.

Issue arises when I try to **check in the Solution** into TFS.

> C:\projects\tfs-workspace\tfs-team-1\tfs-branch-1\solution-1\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\net20\Newtonsoft.Json.dll: **Could not find a part of the path** C:\projects\tfs-workspace\tfs-team-1\tfs-branch-1\solution-1\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\net20\Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Newtonsoft.Json version 11.0.2 is installed in the project. I've cleaned the solution and reinstalled Newtonsoft.Json latest version 11.0.2, as well as added this to web.config:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Not sure where Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4 is being referenced or why this error is coming up. I want to mention again - the solution builds and runs just fine.

Comment: Are you using any tf ignore file?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT not in this team project

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT the way i resolved it is just to exclude nuget packages from source control. using this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143925/get-tfs-to-ignore-my-packages-folder

Answer (score 0):

Usually we do not suggest directly adding the dll to source control instead of using nuget package to handle them.

First please double check if you are using any **tf ignore** files, which may prevent the dlls be checked in. Then check if the dll used in some other projects and have relationship with your project. This may caused the issue.

Also back up your local files, and delete the old workspace, create a totally new one, then check check in files again, which may do the trick.

If all above is not work, then you could use nuget to handle all dlls.